# Cross join SqlServer

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

Query I tried

```
select '' as Date,'opening Balance' as Descriptions ,0.00 as credit,0.00 as 
 debit,Opening as Balance from dbo.Setting
 where Opening!=0

 union all 

 select  (convert(Varchar(20),EDate,105)) as Date,LocName as 
Descriptions,Amount as credit,0.00 as debit,Opening+Amount  as Balance
from dbo.CashInward
inner join dbo.OutletMst ON dbo.OutletMst.LocId = CashInward.OutletId
cross join setting 
where Edate=convert(Datetime,'03/Apr/2018',105) and deletes!=1 and 
Outletmst.Active=1 and Amount!=0

union all

select  (convert(Varchar(20),EDate,105)) as Date,AcName as 
Descriptions,Amount as credit,0.00 as debit,Opening+Amount  as Balance  
from dbo.IncExpEntry
inner join dbo.AccountMst ON dbo.AccountMst.Acid = IncExpEntry.Acid
cross join setting
where ETYpe =1 and Edate=convert(Datetime,'03/Apr/2018',105) and Amount!=0

union all

select (convert(Varchar(20),EDate,105)) as Date,AcName as Descriptions,0.00 
as credit,Amount as debit,Opening-Amount  as Balance from dbo.IncExpEntry
inner join dbo.AccountMst ON dbo.AccountMst.Acid = IncExpEntry.Acid
cross join setting
where ETYpe =2 and Edate=convert(Datetime,'03/Apr/2018',105)  and Amount!=0
```

o/p

[image]

**i want Balance as credit then 6700000+credit else debit 6700000-debit but the 
2nd,3rd,... row i want 6700000+credit+Amount  else 670000-debit-amount**

[image]

Comment: update the opening balance ? in joins

Comment: Can not clearly understand thee expected output, please also post expected output

Comment: what version of `SQL Server` are you using ?

Comment: This is very unclear. One big part of posting a question is (amazingly) asking a question. They end with a question mark (`?`). You haven't actually asked one. I suggest, firstly, explaining your goals and asking your question(s). Then provide Some sample data that we can **consume**. For example [Forum Etiquette: How to post Sample data for a T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/) and finally your expected results. That image doesn't look like SSMS, or it's an old version (SSMS 2005 maybe?). Are you really using such an old version of SQL Server?

Comment: i updated check last image

Comment: i am using SQL server Query Analyzer

Comment: you are using `SQL Server 2000` ? if you are not sure, you can find out the version at the Query Window there execute `PRINT @@VERSION`

Comment: thanks for co-ordination guys i found that answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer

```
      foreach (GridViewRow row in Daybook.Rows)
            {
                string type1 = "0.00";
                string type2 = "0.00";
                 string opening=ltype.Text;
                 string opening2;

               //  int index = row.RowIndex - 1;
                 if (row.Cells[1].Text != type1)
                {

                        decimal Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[1].Text);
                        Decimal Total = Convert.ToDecimal(opening) + Amount;
                        row.Cells[3].Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(Total, 2));
                        //opening2 = Total.ToString();


                }
                 if (row.Cells[2].Text != type2)
                 {
                     decimal Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[2].Text);
                     Decimal Total = Convert.ToDecimal(opening) - Amount;
                     row.Cells[3].Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(Total, 2));
                 }


            }
```